# How to cite RFC using natbib

Tags: bibtex, xetex

I would like to cite an RFC in my xelatex scrbook class with natbib as [RFCXXX] style, for example:

in file body:

```
this is my rfc citation [RFCXXX]
```

and in my bibliography print

```
[RFCXXX] authors, year....
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually create RFC documentation for personal usage. To achieve similar format, you can use `biblatex` package with `style=alphabetic` and add

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\thefield{entrykey}}
```

after loading `biblatex` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, natbib=true, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\thefield{entrykey}}

\addbibresource{rfc.bib}

\begin{document}

    Using biblatex~\cite{RFC1945}

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i can't use biblatex, it's not compatible with multibib

Comment: @Yba, for natbib, I can only suggest to edit `*.bbl` manually. Using `alpha` style will produce `bibitem` in form `\bibitem[BLFF96]{RFC1945}`. So, you can change it to `\bibitem[RFC1945]{RFC1945}` and will produce the same result with `biblatex`.

Comment: thanks this solution works, but it's not scalable !! i have more then 100 references